# Walking Directions iPhone App

Tags: maps, mapkit

I was given the task to write an iPhone app that gives walking directions. I own an Android and I know this is possible within Google Maps and Google Navigation. I am fairly new to MapKit and Google Maps API and it is unclear from what I've Googled if Apple and/or Google support this feature via an API. Can somebody please share some light on this subject?

Comment: not sure of what question you're asking exactly, please clarify

Comment: Is there an API from Google or Apple that allows you to render walking directions from point A to point B, using MapKit? How about using Google Maps inside a UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of is to call a URL from you app, which will be handled by the iPhone's Maps application.  It accepts the parameters `saddr` and `daddr`. You can use the keyword "Current+Location" to use the user's current loc as a parameter:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino
```

Have a look at the [Apple Docs on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) for more info. Hope this helps =)